# Ruby on Rails 2.3.8: Testing: How do I set up an instance variable to use throughout my tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing

Lets say I have some data that remanis the same throughout all of my tests, for forever and eternity.  I create this data in `setup`.  I store the data to `@instance_var`. But when I call @instance_var.attribute in any test, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

I know my instance variable isn't null, cause after it is set, I can do a puts @instance_var.inspect on it...

Any ideas?

EDIT:

```
 setup do
    user = Factory(:user)
    account = Factory(:account)    

    set_user(user)
    set_account(account)


    puts "||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||" #this proves that the instance vars are not null
    puts "| object_test.rb                            |"
    puts "|      #{@user.name}                   "
    puts "|      #{@account.name}                "
    puts "||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
  end
```

A failing test (with the error above)

```
test "for detection of first content with multiple contents" do
      object = Factory(:object, :user_id => @user.id, :account_id => @account.id)
   ... #the rest of this test isn't important, as it is the above line, on @user, where the nil.id error occers
```

in test_helper.rb

```
def set_user(user)
  @user = user
end

def set_account(account)
  @account = account
end
```

I don't really think I need these two methods, as when I define the @instance variable in setup, I get teh same result

in test_helper.rb there are some constants set fore ActiveSupport::TestCase:

```
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  self.use_instantiated_fixtures  = false

  fixtures :all
```

disabling these did nothing. =(

Comment: I think the error is reporting that the id method is being called on some null object. Are you sure that this null object is @instance_var, and not some other possibly related object?

Comment: yes. I'm 500% sure I've typed everything correctly.  The variable I'm using is @user. kinda hard to misspell that =D

Comment: Perhaps if you posted your setup and the test that is failing, we could know more and maybe help you out. More pairs of eyes always is a good thing.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using an constant variable.

Comment: @buruzaemon +1. We need to see your setup and failing test.

Comment: Constant, instance, whatever style, I need data shared between tests.

Comment: Added =D <3 I hope it helps you guys. o wait.. I need to add one more thing.

Comment: there =D If you guys need anything more let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to make a shared class, shared_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class SharedTest
  def self.initialize_testing_data
    self.reset_the_database

    self.set_up_user_and_account
    # make sure our user and account got created 
    puts "|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
    puts "| The user and account "
    puts "| we'll be testing with:"
    puts "|             #{@user.name}"
    puts "|             #{@user.account.name}"
    puts "|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
  end

  def self.reset_the_database
    #clear the database and reset it
    call_rake("db:test:prepare")
    call_rake("db:bootstrap RAILS_ENV=test")
  end

  def self.set_up_user_and_account
    #set up our user for doing all our tests (this person is very busy)  
    @user = Factory(:user)
    @account = Factory(:account)    
    @user.account = @account
    @user.save
  end
end
```

so then at the top of every test file that needs user and account to stay the same between all the tests, you just do

```
require 'shared_test.rb'
```

and methods are called like

```
SharedTest.initialize_testing_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
setup do
  @user = Factory(:user)
  @account = Factory(:account)
end
```

Normally, if you set the instance variables in the setup block, they should be available to all your tests. (You might be having an issue with scopes.)

Comment: as stated in my question, that doesn't work =(. Imma experiment with the constants set in test_helper though, and see if those are preventing anything.